# Can't make right condition for the loop to element when loop goes first time with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two arrays:

```
var myArr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var indexes = [1,2,4];
```

And I want a simple loop that will remove elements from `myArray` by the indexes that are stored in the `indexes` array. For example, given the two arrays above the function should return `[0, 3, 5, 6, 7]`

Here's what I currently have tried but it's not working:

```
for (let i of indexes) {
  if(i == 1) {
    myArr.splice(i, 1);
  } else {
    myArr.splice(i-1, 1);
  }
}
console.log(myArr);
```

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Yes, I know this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is remove elements by index this is a much easier way to handle it.

**es6+**

```js
var myArr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
var indexes = [1,2,4]

myArr.filter((element, index) => !indexes.includes(index))
```

**es5**

```js
var myArr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var indexes = [1,2,4];

myArr.filter(function (element, index) {
    return !indexes.includes(index)
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You really helped me, your code is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

First of arrays are zero-indexed. The first iteration of the loop is always index 0.

Here's what I think you want

```
var myArr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var indexes = [1,2,4];

for (let i of indexes) {
    if(i == 0) {
      myArr.splice(i, 1);
    } else {
      myArr.splice(i-1, 1);
    }
  }
  console.log(myArr);
```

Your code fixed and enhanced

```
indexes.forEach(index => {
    index === 0 ?
        myArr.splice(index, 1) :
        myArr.splice(i-1, 1);
});
```

If you simply wanted to remove a value by index specified in the indexes.

```
indexes.forEach(index => {
    myArr.splice(index, 1);
});
```

Comment: He is iterating the `indexes` array however, so that `i` would actually start at 1 (the `indexes` first element is 1)

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the alteration you want to make, it's to be able to use any element at a variable first index in `indexes` if that's the case, your current code can be altered as such:

```
var myArr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var indexes = [1,2,4];

for (let i of indexes) {
    if(indexes.indexOf(i) == 0) {
      myArr.splice(i, 1);
    } else {
      myArr.splice(i-1, 1);
    }
  }
  console.log(myArr);
```

This will check to see if the index being iterated over is the first in the array.

If you change your code to a regular for loop you can do the following:

```
var myArr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var indexes = [1,2,4];

for (let i = 0; i < indexes.length; i += 1) {
    if(i === 0) {
      myArr.splice(indexes[i], 1);
    } else {
      myArr.splice(indexes[i-1], 1);
    }
  }
  console.log(myArr);
```